How can I get write some debug to a file on a .Net Azure App Services website?
I have a .net app that i can debug locally and i write some debug to a file on the c:\temp\debug.log file.
When i deploy my app this wont work. How can i do something similar in Azure , by writing to a file or having a look at what the error may be ?

Ideally, you should be using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging's ILogger instead of writing your own log file...

is there and example of this ?

There are various ways to register debug messages in Azure Web Service. I hope that the below link might give the details you require Add log messages in code

First of all, you would be needing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging Nuget package installed, and then implement a logger using ILogger.
While you can still write the debug logs to a (local) file in the application file system, a slightly better approach would be to write the debug messages in to a blob storage by appending debug entries to a file (in to similar approach to: How to write in next line of file blob in Azure with function).
However, you are still not getting the full cloud-native benefits, unless you are using a centralized log management, log aggregation capabilities of Azure, utlizing services like; "Azure Log Analytics", "Azure Monitor".
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureMonitor;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging(builder =>
            {
                builder.AddAzureMonitor(config =>
                {
                    config.WorkspaceId = "<Log_Analytics_Workspace_ID>";
                    config.Authentication = new DefaultAzureCredential();
                });
            })
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
        logger.LogDebug("Sample debug message.");
    }
}

